# Generic Class Name for RTS

Tags: game-loop, rts, oop

Hopefully this will be a nice easy question :-

I am building an RTS as a way of learning OOP techniques.

Currently the code has the following classes

```
Class MustInherit GameUnit

Class MustInherit Building
  Inherits GameUnit

Class MustInherit Vehicle
  Inherits GameUnit

Class MustInherit ??????
  Inherits GameUnit

Class Jeep
  Inherits Vehicle

Class WeaponsFactory
  Inherits Building

Class Grenadier
  Inherits ??????
```

I am looking for the generic name for people to replace the ?????, ideally a word that describes people of any race or culture - humanoid or otherwise.  As this is a learning exercise I would like to get it right - using the ...Is A... idea of class inheritance.

For Example:   Jeep IS A Vehicle, Vehicle IS A GameUnit.

Thanks

Comment: Try "Unit" as a class name,

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your input, but I would think that Unit would be too vague, eg. Grenadier IS A Unit, but equally a Jeep could be seen as a unit, for example Jeep Is A Unit would pass as acceptable when reading, but Jeep IS A Soldier would not, as its obvious that a Jeep is NOT a Soldier.

Comment: @VaughanHilts Unit is a very generic name which is likely to clash with the standard library of whatever programming language the OP is using.

Comment: @Philipp: Which is why many programming languages have namespaces. You shouldn't have to use an inappropriate name just because it's a short word.

Comment: Hmm a downvote already, apparently my question does not show any research effort, is unclear or or not useful.  I wonder which it is?

Comment: Soldier maybe? Or Infantry when it also applies to non-combatants.

Comment: @Graham: BTW, I hope your "learning exercise" teaches you the folly of using inheritance for this. In many RTS games, different types of units have different properties. Terran buildings in StarCraft can fly. In SC2, Spine/Spore Crawlers can uproot and move. Vehicles can transform into infantry. And so on. Hard, static inheritance can't handle this.

Comment: The current structure that I have in place is as follows:

Comment: Unit Class contains all the base information such as Health, all Units have health.  At the next layer is the generalised classes such as vehicle, building etc.  the vehicle class impliments an IMove interface for example, then the actual class for the unit such as Jeep.  The jeep will impliment an interface for IGuard, IPatrol etc.  I have a large list of Interfaces, but what makes it in is still to be decided - currently IMove,IBuild,IGarrison,IGuard,IPatrol,IFire,IFly,IRadar,IRadarJam.  Its hard going but progress so far has been good. :)

Comment: @Graham I would say the question in too localized, not constructive, and off topic. It is a question that would better be answered by a historian or English major than a game developer.

Comment: You're just wanting a discussion, this would be more of a question for a chat room or forum, not a Q/A site. See the [FAQ] about what types of questions to ask here and what type not to ask. This falls under the "chatty" questions category.

Comment: I dont want a chat, I want an answer.  On a site with so many game developers, surely someone has developed an RTS game with proper class structure and naming convention.  This is a simple question, that must have been tackled by many a developer.  As I stated in the question, I am learning game developement and wanted to know what the proper name is.  I think Philipp may be right with infantry.  Could anyone who has created an RTS using Buldings, Vehicles and People let me know what they called there 'people'.  Thanks

Comment: The point is there is no *proper* name. You can call it whatever you want. **Just pick a name and move on**. Learning game development isn't about what to name things. You are learning something very important with this question: Don't sweat the small things, just make a decision and move on. Design indecision is something that cripples the development of many games. Getting hung up on something this small means you've identified design indecision as an improvement area for yourself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When a Jeep is a Vehicle, then a Grenadier seems to differs from it by the fact that it moves on foot. So I would recommend to name the base-class for these units Infantry.

Infantry comes from the latin word infans which describes a child which has learned to walk on its own. It was used to describe a soldier who walks into battle instead of using a horse or charriot.